# npm run start doesn't do anything and opens empty command prompt

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

Trying to get my project to run. We were previously working with rescript which I try to remove. When I run `npm run start` it does not seem to do anything and an empty command prompt pops up. `ignore-scripts` has already been set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved; had some issue pointing it back to `react-scripts`